# Connect a SharePoint 2010 Calendar View to Outlook 2010

Tags: 2010, calendar, outlook

We would like to present a "My View" of a divisional calendar to users within Outlook.  The standard "Connect to Outlook" does a great job of setting up the calendar in Outlook, unfortunately there is no way to set this to use a specific View.  Ideally we would like the Calendar entries to be integrated into the users calendar.  Any ideas on how to make this work, even with 3rd party solutions?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

There isn't anyway to do this out of the box with SharePoint and I am unaware of any purchasable third-party or open source solution to this scenario.

With that said, you could accomplish this with a bit of custom code.  Outlook lets you add "Internet Calendars" in ICS format.  You could write some custom code in a Visual Studio SharePoint Solution that grabs the list items you want (in the View you want) and the generate an ICS output (kind of like generating your own custom RSS feed).

Comment: There is a project on Sourceforge that is a .NET library for working with the iCal (ICS) format: http://sourceforge.net/projects/dday-ical/

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid that was the answer, darn it.  For the life of me I don't understand which MS doesn't enable this.

Comment: Different products that function completely differently I'm afraid